# C - Converting hex into char array

Tags: c

I have an `unit32_t` in hex format : `uint32_t a = 0xdddddddd`
how can I convert it into an

```
array[8] = {0,x,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d}
```

I tried to use :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
array[i] = (a & (0x80 >> i)) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question asks how to put 10 chars into an 8 byte array. It's impossible. Perhaps you will edit the question to clarify what it is you are trying to achieve. Do you want a 10+1 character string (eg: "0x1234ABCD") or do you want to spread 4 bytes across 8 bytes, still as "binary" values... This question, as it is, cannot be answered.

Comment: Sorry it is my first time using stack overflow. I will do my best to explain the question next time :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are referring to using the array to store every hex digit in a place in the array then you can do:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        array[i] = a & 0x0F;
        a = a >> 4;
    }
```

where every time, we get the right most hex digit (which is 4 bits) and assign that to the array and then we shift left `a` to get the next right most 4 bits as every hex digit is 4 bits indeed.

but if you are referring to converting that hex number into a string then you can use the function called `itoa` with the **base = 16**. but notice that `itoa()` is not a `C` standard function. It is a non-standard extension provided by a specific implementation.

so you can write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(void)
{
    uint32_t a = 0xdddddddd;
    char array[10];
    itoa(a, array, 16);
    printf("array = 0x%s\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
array = 0xdddddddd
```

Comment: Good deal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another conforming implementation can simply use `snprintf()` as intended to write the representation of the number in `a` in hex to `array`. In that case, all that is needed is a sufficiently sized `array` and:

```c
    snprintf (array, sizeof array, "%x", a);
```

See: [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [C18 Standard - 7.21.6.5 The snprintf function](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf)

A short example outputting each element of `array` after filling with `a` would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void) {
  
  char array[16] = "";
  uint32_t a = 0xdddddddd;
  
  /* write a to array in hex validatating array was of sufficient size */
  if ((size_t)snprintf (array, sizeof array, "%x", a) >= sizeof array)
    fputs ("warning: representation of 'a' truncated.\n", stderr);
  
  /* output results */
  for (int i = 0; array[i]; i++)
    printf ("array[%2d] : '%c'\n", i, array[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hex2char
array[ 0] : 'd'
array[ 1] : 'd'
array[ 2] : 'd'
array[ 3] : 'd'
array[ 4] : 'd'
array[ 5] : 'd'
array[ 6] : 'd'
array[ 7] : 'd'
```